# PHP 7 usort adds equal items to end of array where in PHP 5 it adds to the beginning

Tags: php, php-7, usort

There seems to be an undocumented change to how PHP 7 handles equal results in usort functions.

```
$myArray = array(1, 2, 3);
usort($myArray, function($a, $b) { return 0; });
print_r($myArray);

// PHP 5:
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 1
)

// PHP 7
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
```

In other words in PHP 7, usort is adding equal values to the end of the array, whereas PHP 5 adds them to the beginning. I can't find any mention of this behaviour.

Is there a way of forcing the PHP 5 behaviour?

Comment: I don't think `usort` was ever guaranteed to be stable nor was the sort order of equal elements ever defined. If you relied on the *undefined behaviour*, you need to change your approach.

Comment: So it was undocumented behaviour in PHP 5, and it still is in PHP 7?

Comment: @Blowski: It's explicitly documented as undefined.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php):

> If two members compare as equal, their relative order in the sorted array is undefined.

Relying on undefined behavior is a bad idea. There is no way to change the behavior (apart from making the items not equal).